# mysql: ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'mysql-native-password' is not loaded

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, mysql, database

I just installed a fresh install of mysql-server-5.7 no linux mint 19.1.
I wasn't prompted to set a root password during the installation and so whenever I tried to use mysql via the `mysql -u root -p` command.
I got this error => `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.

So I searched stack overflow and found an answer that involved setting the authentication plugin to `mysql_native_password`. the query looked something like this...

```
UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password";
```

However, for some reason I typed the command manually instead of copying it and I seem to have written `mysql-native-password` instead of `mysql_native_password` (stupid me!!!)

now I tried to access the mysql shell in various ways but I always get the following error!

```
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'mysql-native-password' is not loaded
```

I tried...

```
$sudo mysql -u root 
$sudo mysql
$mysql -u root -p
$mysql_upgrade ...
$sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

but everything returned the same ERROR
HELP!!!

Comment: Have you found a solution. I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was in the same boat - I managed to fix the issue by uninstalling mySQL completely and running a fresh install.  I used the following commands for the uninstallation:

```
sudo -i
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
deluser --remove-home mysql
delgroup mysql
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
updatedb
exit
```

Then running a fresh install as per your operating system requirements (in my case Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Comment: Thanks for your Good Answer.